# Saving an SQL Server view to the Dynamics AX AOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have found there are significant advantages to writing views in SQL Server Management Studio rather than creating them in the AOT. However, it appears that

- Views created in SQL Server are not accessible from X++ code and do not appear in the AOT.
- Views created in the AOT and then modified in SQL Server Management studio can be accessed from X++ code but are overwritten when the AOT view is recompiled or synchronized.

Is there any way around this problem? Ideally SQL views could be reengineered to be saved in the AOT, but this doesn't appear to be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had a requirement for view that could not be designed in AOT.

Our workaround approach:

1. design view in AOT with fields only (computed columns with appropriate EDTs) - just add any table (main one)
2. create static server view method with SQL DDL (from SSMS) and execute that [ddl](/questions/tagged/ddl) with [`Statement.executeQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/statement.executequery.aspx)
3. call this static method at DB Synchonize ([`Application.dbSynchronize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/application.dbsynchronize.aspx))

Comment: If we are using Statement.executeQuery will their necessarily be any need to have any version of the view saved in the AOT - as the view would not be referenced in any X++ code?

Comment: Do you need this *View* inside AX or not? If you need this in AX, then you have to AOT. If only external applications will use this view directly on the database, then you don't need this view in AOT - only automate creation at DB Synchronyze.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your answer. I thought you were suggesting calling Statement.executeQuery from everywhere I wanted to access the view. Clearly that is not what you were suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the syncronization process in X++ to avoid this but it's really not recommended. Manually created or modified views are in a high risk of avoid security from AOT, for example. Just in case you have severe performance problems this could be worth the risk.

The sync process is always AOT->SQL, so the design process may have this into account.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, in the end we modified our requirements to avoid doing this.